# Are plethories a theory of basis-free polynomials?

Tags: plethory, polynomials, ac.commutative-algebra

This question is a follow-up to a [question about the theory of polynomials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73664/what-is-the-theory-of-polynomials).

It should be quite clear by now that [matrix theory and linear algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11669/what-is-the-difference-between-matrix-theory-and-linear-algebra) are quite different topics.  As the various answers to that question clearly state, the difference is largely because of *basis choice*.  But we know how to do a lot of abstract linear algebra, without ever having to choose a basis.

But when one switches to polynomials, the situation changes: even very general definitions of polynomials (like that in Lang's Algebra, for example) still use monomials in the standard basis.  Why that basis, and not the [rising factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RisingFactorial.html) basis, or [falling factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FallingFactorial.html), or [Chebyshev basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials), or any other?  And the most important question: why, in fact, choose a basis at all?

Which leads to the question in the title: Are plethories a theory of basis-free polynomials?

I think the motivation should be clear: if going 'basis free' was so successful for linear algebra, shouldn't we also expect similar success with polynomials?  Unfortunately, I have not been able to find any work which I could readily understand as being about developing a theory of basis-free polynomials.

EDIT: After reading the current comments and answers, I am starting to think that perhaps what I am really seeking is a theory for *basis-independent* polynomials, or even *basis-generic* rather than leaping right away to basis-free.  There are many applications of polynomials where bases other than the monomial one greatly simplify both reasoning and computations (which is what I am eventually after), but the tools for doing this seem to be hard to find.

Comment: Is "plethory" a real tag?   Or "polynomial" for that matter?  Too many tags to keep track of.

Comment: @Jim: there were not real tags, until now...  I welcome suggestions on that front.

Comment: There is a tag "polynomials" already in use...

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you would want to be able to do with a basis-free description of polynomials.  My inner category theorist wants to know what you would consider to be the morphisms between spaces of polynomials - if there are any: my experience (which isn't much) is that we tend to think of spaces of polynomials one at a time, whereas we work with lots of vector spaces at the same time.  Plethories are more like rings: the right way to move between them is via bimodules.  If that's the sort of thing you want, then maybe they are the right description for you.

Comment: The Grothendieck ring of finite dimensional representations of $SL(2)$ is isomorphic to the polynomial ring. The monomial basis is given by taking tensor powers of the fundamental representation. A more natural basis are the irreducible representations (which happen to be the symmetric powers of the fundamental representation). The irreducible representations then correspond to the Chebychev polynomials; so this example, which you mention, is studied. 

Answer (score 5):

Some naive remarks. It seems to me that the simplest reason to choose the standard basis is because it exhibits the universal property of a polynomial ring.

One way to exhibit a partially basis-free definition of a polynomial ring is to define it as the symmetric algebra on a vector space. This retains the grading but is otherwise basis-free. If one wants to ignore the grading then I am not sure what options are available and depending on the application it may not be natural to ignore the grading.

Comment: Let me add that many basic (and some not so basic) homological constructions have basis free definitions - for example one can easily define the Koszul resolution using the exterior algebra.


Comment: +1.  The distinction seems to be whether you take the left adjoint of the "underlying set" functor or the "underlying module" functor from commutative rings.


Comment: One may ignore the grading when describing a symmetric algebra through its universal property: a module map from the vector space to a commutative algebra extends uniquely to an algebra map. It is a happy and useful circumstance that this ungraded problem has a graded solution.

Comment: I do not want to ignore the grading - it is there in all choices of basis, so I don't see a good a priori reason why it would disappear when we go basis-free.

Comment: @Jacques: I don't know what you mean by "it is there in all choices of basis." Certainly all the examples you've written down implicitly give the same _filtration_ on polynomials, but it is possible to write down bases where this is not the case (for example $x, x^3 - x^2, x^3 + x^2, x^4, x^5, ...$). @Wilberd: what I meant by "ignore the grading" is giving an abstract description of a polynomial ring that doesn't distinguish any of its elements (in the symmetric algebra description we distinguish the elements of degree $1$). 